# How can I compare the performance of PHP to Perl?

Tags: php, performance, perl

Although both are interpreted languages there are differences or?

What are the performance differences of both languages?
Even if Perl would be faster than PHP, the most would choose PHP, because of the simplicity of PHP.
Does someone have experience in this regard?

Comment: When you wrote similar programs in each language, and ran them, what did you see?

Comment: It depends on tasks you're solving.

Comment: @s.lott i would see the results, but i cant compare the performance of both

Comment: The simplicity of PHP? Where's that then? :) (Seriously, the "simplicity" of either language is arguable. People tend towards PHP because it has low barriers to entry, getting a Perl programming running on web hosting tends to be a bit more effort.)

Comment: @streetparade: What distinction are you making?   Comparing the results of similar programs *is* comparing performance.  How can you say you want one and not the other?  What are you talking about?  Please update the question to explain what you want.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Rarely is performance enough of a factor to make that the decider between languages. Different languages are suitable to solving different tasks, and also the knowledge and expertise of the programmer is very important.

Comment: David Dorward: It is easy to run Perl program on any hosting. mod_perl is another thing, but you can get virtual server for $20/month if you need such performance or FastCGI for $45/year.

Comment: Yes, most hosting providers will give you the tools needed to run Perl programs, but you often have to assemble them yourself - installing modules, etc. - while PHP applications tend to be solely a matter of unzipping the program.  For a technically-unsophisticated user who just wants to have a working blog (or whatever), that's a world of difference, even if it's no big deal to those of us who write code on a daily basis and have previously done dozens of similar installs.

Comment: It's not easy to run Perl from *any* hosting. It's easy to find hosting where it is easy to run Perl, though, but that's a different thing. The problem is that people are too cheap to even buy a basic hosting account that would save them a lot of time and trouble. They'd rather waste time and energy trying to make a crippled free account work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The Computer Language Benchmarks Game](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/faster/perl-php.html) compares several programming languages.

Comment: Makes me glad for the time I spent submitting better code for Perl -- a couple months ago it was losing most of those benchmarks. Then again that's *also* proof that the difference between good and bad code often outweighs the difference between one language implementation and another :)

Comment: @hobbs "proof that the difference between good and bad code" perhaps proof that code which runs on 4 cores sometimes is faster than code that only runs on one core ;-)

Comment: I'm in doubt about this side, http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/performance.php?test=regexdna runs faster with perl but php is #2 in list...?

Comment: PHP has had large speed improvements in php7.  But when you start looking into some other tasks perl will pass php.  I know a few companies who do all the basics in php, but use other languages to process heavy data.  Php does the basics good.  I am not a huge fan of php, but you have to give it credit where credit is do.  I would rather go with perl because it has a huge range. PHP is so simple, but limited and this is what allows it to run so fast now days.

Answer (score 26):

First, you have to define what you mean by "performance", and how much you're willing to give up to get that.

Most people would tell you that this means something like "completes the task the fastest". That's not very interesting though. If you wanted a really fast solution, you shouldn't be using either PHP or Perl. You want to get as close to the bare metal as possible. Higher level languages waste a lot of time because they are general purpose tools. They have to be ready to do anything, not just what you want to do. As such, they give up some speed for flexibility.

Oh, but programming at such a low level takes too long and isn't portable. So now you have to factor in the development time it takes you to get to the point where you program is merely acceptably fast. If it completes in the blink of an eye, do you need need it to finish in half a blink? Maybe a high-level language is sufficiently speedy.

Some people will tell you Perl (or some other language) is really easy, and it is for the experienced programmer. That doesn't help you if you don't know Perl yet, though. The language doesn't really matter. If you know PHP but not Perl, maybe you can have a PHP solution tonight. If you go through my [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001322/) book, which a reasonable person can do in about 40 hours if they do all of the exercises, maybe you have a Perl solution in two weeks. Vice versa, a person with reasonable Perl skills might have a Perl solution tonight, but a PHP solution in a week. That extra developer time might not be worth it.

A common problem I see with any sort of programmer, however, is the root cause of most inefficiency: they simply don't know how to program and neither do they care. Sure, they can make a syntactically valid program, and they can string together a series of Rube Goldbergesque statements that eventually give the desired effect, but they don't know how to design, make efficient use of resources, and so on.

One such pretender I had to evaluate insisted that the company buy more hardware despite CPU utilization never topping 5%. He made huge in-memory hashes to configure everything, taking up 500 MB per hash and running on 16 apache child processes. His very simple program to upload a file and put it in a database was constrained by the physical amount of RAM in the machine. His performance was really low because he didn't know what he was doing. That he was using Perl didn't matter.

Indeed, a now deleted answer on this site used 16GB to [generate 100 random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899362/how-can-i-generate-non-repetitive-random-4-bytes-hex-values-in-perl/1899863#1899863). If you know how to design programs, you're not going to do stupid things like that in any language.

Some people like to point at benchmarks for toy programs. The problem is that you're never interested in writing toy programs, so the benchmarks are irrelevant. Tim Bray ran a [Winde Finder](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/10/30/WF-Results) competition, and try as he might to make a Ruby or Erlang solution come out on top, Perl took the prize. Don't get too excited about that though. Notice that the top 20 solutions came from only a handful of people, and that most languages also had very poor solutions. Some of the top solutions were in Erlang, even though Tim himself wasn't skilled enough in Erlang to get those results (and he's no slouch, mind you). He also notes that the Ruby solutions ran faster on a Mac laptop than they did on Sun's T5120. Not only that, but many of the top solutions, no matter the language, used the same technique: they mmapped a file. The programs were basically the same. Getting the picture yet? The programming language isn't even close to being the important decision.

Now maybe some people start to see the productivity angle: how much do I have to put in for what I get out? Many of my Perl colleagues will scoff at PHP, make snide remarks about its design, and so on, but they completely ignore the fact that for some basic things, you have to put in very little to get out what you need. However, they are probably right that you sacrifice a lot tying yourself into PHP's model. Maybe PHP gives you a short-term win, which is completely valid, but betting the farm on it might not be the right long-term solution, say, when you want to move to web services instead of web pages (I'm looking at you, Sourceforge).

And it just keeps going on from there. You have to figure out what you want for "performance", figure out how all of your choices impact that, then choose the solution that's right for you. That's a long way to say that no one can answer this question for you, and that even for you, the answer might change based on new requirements.

Comment: It's actually an entire chapter in Mastering Perl, and a couple of my podcasted talks: http://www252.pair.com/comdog/ . And, why can't StackOverflow be my blog. :)

Comment: "A common problem I see with any sort of programmer, however, is the root cause of most inefficiency: they simply don't know how to program and neither do they care." +1 just for that sentence. So clear, so succinct, and so damn relevant to most programming-related questions/problems. Too bad it's CW, yeah, and also too bad I can't give a second +1 for the rest of the answer.

Comment: You are on the money,  half of my jobs are to redo the backend of websites, making them faster and smaller. But most of the time someone just throws together a bunch of garbage that i can't believe works.  It isn't strange for me to reduce a website's backend by 60%.  It is just that bad most of the time.  This is so common with php as it is easy to learn and very flexible.

Answer (score 5):

There is quite a lot of information on this which is easily available. 
Took about 1 minute on Google to find these hits and  a few more ...

- http://www.skitoy.com/p/performance-of-python-php-and-perl/160
- http://www.whenpenguinsattack.com/2006/08/08/php-vs-perl/
- http://tnx.nl/php.html

**Edit:** By the way; is there a particular problem you're trying to solve? I think it will be easier to get a good answer if you give an example :)

Comment: Agreed.  IMO, without a particular problem, this kind of question is a waste of time for all concerned.

Answer (score 0):

i created a hello world app and run it for 1000 time.

PHP is much slower than PERL in this case.

hello.pl

```
print "Hello, World!\n";
```

Result:

```
time for i in `seq 1000`; do perl ./hello.pl >/dev/null; done
```

> real    0m1.001s
>   user    0m0.039s
>   sys     0m0.083s

hello.php

```
<?php print "Hello World!"; ?>
```

Result:

```
time for i in `seq 1000`; do php ./hello.php >/dev/null; done
```

> real    0m35.788s
>   user    0m24.373s
>   sys     0m4.592s